# Swift - Locking/tapping a button

Tags: swift, uibutton

I am making a game with dices. The idea is to hold/lock a die. I made the dices as buttons so now they can be tapped. Example: I throw a "6" and a "1". I tap the "6", so now only the "1" is going to be thrown.

I'm kinda lost with this one, do I need to make booleans to hold them? Here's my code. I actually don't know where to start.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var dice1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var dice2: UIButton!

var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer!


var randomDiceIndex1 : Int = 0
var randomDiceIndex2 : Int = 0

let diceArray = ["dice1", "dice2", "dice3", "dice4", "dice5", "dice6"]

func playSoundWith(fileName: String, fileExtenstion: String) -> Void {
    let audioSourceURL: URL!
    audioSourceURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, 
    withExtension: fileExtenstion)
    if audioSourceURL == nil {
        print("Geluid werkt niet")
    } else {
        do {

            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer.init(contentsOf: 
            audioSourceURL!)
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            audioPlayer.play()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
updateDiceImages()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}


@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
updateDiceImages()
playSoundWith(fileName: "dobbelstenen", fileExtenstion: "m4a")
}

func updateDiceImages(){
randomDiceIndex1 = Int(arc4random_uniform(6))
randomDiceIndex2 = Int(arc4random_uniform(6))

dice1.setImage(UIImage(named: diceArray[randomDiceIndex1]), for: 
.normal)
dice2.setImage(UIImage(named: diceArray[randomDiceIndex2]), for: 
.normal)  
}

override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEventSubtype, with event: 
UIEvent?) {
updateDiceImages()
playSoundWith(fileName: "dobbelstenen", fileExtenstion: "m4a")
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use booleans to store which dice is locked.

```
var dice1Locked = false 
var dice2Locked = false
```

In the `@OBAction`s of the buttons (i.e. when the buttons are tapped), toggle the booleans:

```
dice1Locked = !dice1Locked
```

Then in `updateDiceImages`, check whether the dice is locked before changing its image:

```
if !dice1Locked {
    randomDiceIndex1 = Int(arc4random_uniform(6))
    dice1.setImage(UIImage(named: diceArray[randomDiceIndex1]), for: 
.normal)
}

if !dice2Locked {
    randomDiceIndex2 = Int(arc4random_uniform(6))
    dice2.setImage(UIImage(named: diceArray[randomDiceIndex2]), for: 
.normal)
}
```

I also recommend you to create model for your dice, instead of using buttons:

```
struct Dice {
    var number: Int
    var locked: Bool
}
```